# Accessing protected variable in googletest

Tags: c++, googletest, protected

I have this class testC that is meant for google testing

```
class testC : public A { };
```

and then bunch of TEST's that are in the same file.

```
TEST(test_case_name, test_name) {
 ... test body ...
}
```

A is structured like this

```
class A{

protected:
   B b;
public:
   //constructors
   //destructor
   //member functions
```

Q: How can I access `b` in all the `TEST(){}` functions through `testC`?

I tried to do a getter in `testC`

```
public:
  testC getTest(){
      testC test;
      return test;
  }
```

and i also tried with returning a reference, but no luck...

Comment: Why are you deriving test classes from your testlings?

Comment: Following the instructions... is there a more optimal way?

Comment: @anhoppe has the right answer to how to do this below, but usually when you run into this, you have to ask *why* you need it. Unit tests should test the expected behavior of the system. If you need to check the behavior of a private member, than you are checking the state of a subsystem. If that subsystem requires such testing, it *usually* should be its own class, with its own set of unit tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the FRIEND_TEST macro provided by googletest. Have a look in the advanced guide  under [**Private class members**](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Private_Class_Members).

You have to declare the test as a friend of the code under test. If I'm not mistaken you have to declare the friendship for all tests that want to access protected members.

```
class MySystemUnderTest
{
    #ifdef _MY_UNIT_TEST
    FRIEND_TEST(MySystemUnderTest_test, functionA_prereq_expected);
    FRIEND_TEST(MySystemUnderTest_test, functionB_prereq_expected);
    #endif

    ...
};
```

In the example above I use the preprocessor symbol _MY_UNIT_TEST to remove the declaration from productive code. The methods *functionA_prereq_expected* and *functionB_prereq_expected* would be defined in the test fixture *MySystemUnderTest_test*.

You have to add the **FRIEND_TEST** declaration in the code under test. That's the price you have to pay if you want to test against protected / private members.

Comment: Do i need to create an object in testC like `private: testC testO;`

Comment: The TEST(testCaseName, testName) definitions do NOT belong to the testC class if I get your code right. They are no members of it and cannot access the protected members, no matter if you return a reference to a testC object or whatever. The only way for your test to access those it to add a FRIEND_TEST(testCaseName, testName) declaration to the testC class. Then the test is a friend and CAN access the protected and private members. But it is true as noted above that this is usually not a good style.

Comment: Look at the link. It really should explain the topic. The advanced guide is really great! With some trying you'll make ur way :-)

Comment: [Updated link here](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#testing-private-code) . **It is important to show here the text in bold** "per the black-box testing principle, most of the time you should test your code through its public interfaces."

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the [`FRIEND_TEST`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/testing.html#FRIEND_TEST) directly into the class to be tested `ClassToTest` surrounded by an `#ifdef` statement (as suggested by the [post by anhoppe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26307454/9938686)) for `protected` members and methods I would **create another class `test::ClassToTest` which inherits from the class to be tested and registers the test suite and the tests as friends** as follows:

Inside file `implementation.hpp`:

```
namespace some {
  namespace complicated {
    namespace ns {
      // Class that we want to test
      class ClassToTest {
        public:
          constexpr ClassToTest() noexcept
            : member_to_be_accessed{7} {
            return;
          }
        protected:
          // The protected member (or method) to be accessed
          int member_to_be_accessed;
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Inside the file `test.hpp`:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "implementation.hpp"


namespace test {
  // The derived class that registers the test fixture and tests as friends
  class ClassToTest : public some::complicated::ns::ClassToTest {
    using some::complicated::ns::ClassToTest::ClassToTest;
    friend class SomeTestFixture;
    FRIEND_TEST(SomeTestFixture, someTest);
  };
  // The test fixture
  class SomeTestFixture : public testing::Test {
    protected:
      SomeTestFixture() noexcept 
        : class_to_test{} {
        return;
      }
      ClassToTest class_to_test;
  };
  // A test
  TEST_F(SomeTestFixture, someTest) {
    EXPECT_EQ(class_to_test.member_to_be_accessed, 7);
  }
}
```

The advantage of this is that you **clearly separate the test from the implementation** and that you can get around the [**restriction regarding namespaces**](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/testing.html#FRIEND_TEST):

> If the class is defined in a namespace, then in order to be friends of
> the class, test fixtures and tests must be defined in the exact same
> namespace, without inline or anonymous namespaces.

---

Furthermore, as pointed out in [**"Testing Private Code" section of the "Advanced GoogleTest Guide"**](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#testing-private-code) generally the black-box approach should be used: Code should be tested through its public interface only. If you can, re-structure your code separating the interface from the implementation using the [Pointer to Implementation (PImpl)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) design strategy and test the internals independently.